# ggplot and ggdendro: issues when writing a function of generating a dendrogram and saving it into a pdf file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrap the ggplot scripts into a function, which is listed as following. However,  running this one gives me the error messages such as

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
>
> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

without wrapping these scripts into a function, they just work fine. Thus, how to write this kind of function, which generates a dendrogram using ggplot and save it into a pdf.

```
nicedendro<-function(inputdat, outputfile){
    library(ggdendro)
    library(ggplot2)
    x <- read.table(inputdat,  head=TRUE)
    y <- 1-x
    d <- as.dist(y,diag=FALSE,upper=FALSE)
    hc <- hclust(d,"ave")
    dhc <- as.dendrogram(hc)
    ddata <- dendro_data(dhc,type="rectangle")
    ddata$labels$text <- gsub("\\."," ",ddata$labels$text)
    pdf(outputfile, width=30,height=35)

    plot(ggplot(segment(ddata)) + 
       geom_segment(aes(x=x0,y=y0,xend=x1,yend=y1)) + 
       xlab(NULL) + 
       ylab(NULL) + 
       scale_x_discrete(limits=ddata$labels$text) + 
       opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank()) + 
       opts(panel.grid.minor=theme_blank()) + 
       coord_flip())


    dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a quite frequently asked question: you have to use `print()` in order to print your graph.

```
d <- function(){
  g1 <- qplot(...)
  print(g1)
}
```

Comment: in addition to not calling print, calling plot on a ggplot object also a bit arcane...might explain the error the OP is getting.

Comment: I was under the impression that with a ggplot2-object that `plot(g1)` would be dispatched to `print(g1)`.

Comment: But I guess I was wrong, and I get the error message mentioned above.